# GPS Coordinates MIssing Compass Points

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, geo

I've been provided a series of Latitude/Longitude coordinates From what I've read this is the correct format: N41 25.117 and W120 58.292

The data provided appears to be missing the N,S,E,W designations?  Is there a way to derive this from the values that are provided to me?

Sample of the data here:

Longitude/Latitude

```
85 36.714   29 46.091
85 58.505   30 04.041
85 58.499   30 04.088
85 36.689   29 45.872
85 36.908   29 46.534
85 42.635   29 44.921
85 42.413   29 46.498
85 29.316   29 43.253
85 29.333   29 44.124
85 40.746   29 43.255
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that the data uses positive values as North and East, while negative values mean South and West.

Comment: Yes, thanks so much! That looks to be correct except W appears to be positive: W85 36.714 N29 46.091

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco west must be negative, otherwise the data format is invalid.